# How to download pdf report in shiny R including all data tables and plots together in one?

Tags: r, shiny, download

I am trying to download a pdf file containing tables and plots all together in single pdf file/report using the following code, but the code is showing some warning.
can someone help me with the following code or by means of any other solution?

waiting for the response

**ui.R**

```
library(gplots)
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)
dashboardBody(
downloadButton("report_file", "Generate report")
 )
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(session,input,output){
output$estimatesPK<-renderTable({
table()
})

output$mean_graph<-renderPlot({
plot()
})
output$log_mean_graph({
plot1()
})
output$individual_graph({
plot2()
})
output$log_individual_graph({
plot3()
})
output$T_R_Ratio_Table({
table1()
})
output$report_file <- downloadHandler(
  # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
  filename = "report_file.pdf",
  content = function(file) {
    # before processing it, 
    # in
    # .
    tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report_file.Rmd")
    file.copy("report_file.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)




    rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                      params = params,
                      envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
    )
  }
)
})
```

**report_file.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Parameterized Report for Shiny"
output: pdf_document
params:
table: 'NULL'
plot: 'NULL'
region: ""
---
```

```
params[["estimatesPK"]]
```

```
params[["mean_graph"]]
```

```
params[["log_mean_graph"]]
```

```
params[["individual_graph"]]
```

```
params[["log_individual_graph"]]
```

```
params[["T_R_Ratio_Table"]]
```

I tried the above code but got the following error

```
   Quitting from lines 11-12 (report_file.Rmd) 

   Warning: Error in eval: object 'params' not found
   [No stack trace available]
```

Comment: Parameters don't work this way.  I would read https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html and test the parameterized rmarkdown outside of the shiny environment before trying to put the two together.

Comment: @RaoulDuke  can you please make the changes? in my code?

Comment: I can only suggest that you start with this example https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html paying special attention to the section of code `# Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
        params <- list(n = input$slider)`.  Your current code is not initializing a `params` object to be called in the `render()` step.  That is the source of your error.